# Example wanted: here string to fd

Tags: bash, io-redirection

`man bash` features this redirection: `[n]<<<word`. With this explanation:

```
The result is supplied as a single string, with a  newline  appended,
to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).
```

I'm trying to get it work, but can't really figure out a solution.

```
$ exec 4>out
$ 4<<<asdfwefwef
```

This doesn't seem to do anything expected.

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty is finding a standard utility that reads from fd4. This illustrates that fd4 gets the string:

```
$ ( cat 0<&4 ) 4<<<'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
$
```

Or you could use `read -u` to smuggle a string into a script without using stdin or an argument:

```
$ read -u 4 FOO 4<<<42 && echo $FOO
42
$
```

In practice, the read would be buried deep in the script, and the script would inherit the fd4 redirection from the command line.

```
$ cat Fd4
#! /bin/bash

#.. Read from stdin
read -r A B C
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' $A $B $C $D $E

#.. Read from here string.
read -r -u4 D B E
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' $A $B $C $D $E


$ echo stdin gets this | ./Fd4 4<<<'fd4 sees that'
stdin gets this  
stdin sees this fd4 that
$
```